# Haproxy on server failure event

Tags: haproxy, failover

I've got a setup with one HAproxy server (frontend) and multiple web-servers (backend). Is it possible to configure HAproxy so that a script is executed when a web-server gets down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're asking is you want to send a mail when one of the backend servers goes down, correct?  I don't believe there's a way to trigger this from within HAProxy itself. One way to do this is to have a script check the status of the backends periodically and send an email if a backend is down. You can use the HAProxy socket interface to get this info. Docs are [here](http://www.haproxy.org/#docs).  You'll probably need to parse the output from the `show stat` command.  Good luck!

Comment: HA-Proxy version 1.6 introduced that functionality natively with the [Mailer](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#3.6) Directive.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via HaProxy itself ,it provides you httpchk directive below are some example
Syntax

```
option httpchk
option httpchk <uri>
option httpchk <method> <uri>
option httpchk <method> <uri> <version>
```

Comment: With httpchk I can only specify how to check if server is down and I need a event /callback function that is executed when server gets down.

Comment: What do you mean by event/callback function and what you want to do when your web server goes down?  You mean to say you want to bring up your web server again in case if your IIS/apache get crashed?

Comment: I need to send an email to myself when a webserver node goes down, so basically I need execute a bash script when that happens.

Comment: I believe below script will help you

Answer (score -1):

I believe below script will help you.Please modify it as per your need You need to schedule it in you cron. You can use mailx to send email when apache goes down and when it gets restarted.

```
RESTART="/etc/init.d/httpd restart"

#incase if you are on Deb based boxes
#RESTART="/etc/init.d/apache2 restart"


PGREP="/usr/bin/pgrep"

HTTPD="httpd"

# find httpd pid
$PGREP ${HTTPD}

if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
then
 # restart apache
 $RESTART
fi
```